# multiple LDAP and krbtgt tickets generated

Tags: active-directory, security, kerberos

I was doing some testing to understand Kerberos behavior, I have a user Alice logged into a machine part of lab.local domain, after sign in, I run net user \dc\sysvol to trigger service ticket request for the cifs service, as per my understanding the client now should have two tickets in the cache the first is the TGT and the other is the TGS for cifs service, by running klist, I found that there are two TGT tickets identified by krbtgt account and two LDAP TGS tickets and one cifs ticket, I want to know why there are two TGT not only one and why the LDAP tickets exist ? I added an image for the klist command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJxY2.png)

Comment: The term you're looking for is a "service ticket" (as opposed to a TGT being a "ticket-granting ticket"). "TGS" is not the term for a ticket – it's the component of the KDC that _issues_ tickets.

Answer (score 0):

The two `krbtgt/*` tickets are issued with different flags. Ticket `#1` is the normal TGT that you received during login, while ticket `#0` is a copy that the KDC issued with the `forwarded` flag for *unconstrained delegation*. It's not entirely clear whether it was received by this machine from elsewhere or whether it's about to be forwarded to another machine from yours, though I suspect it's the latter. (Note how the service tickets have the `ok_as_delegate` flag, indicating that those services are marked to allow unconstrained delegation to them.)

The two `ldap/*` tickets are issued for different principal names – notice that ticket `#2` has a two-component principal while ticket `#4` has a three-component one. While typical Kerberos uses only the basic two-component `service/fqdn` service principal format, certain Active Directory services extend this to a three-component `service/fqdn/instance` (which is not unlike how traditional Kerberos has `user/instance`). In this case the 3rd component is the AD domain name that the LDAP server (the DC) is responsible for; I'm not entirely clear on the purpose, although I believe it was documented *somewhere* in MS docs.