# why are multiple Kerberos TGTs visible thru klist?

Tags: kerberos, delegation

I just started trying to understand kerberos and stumbled across the two TGTs on my system too - then I found the post [multiple LDAP and krbtgt tickets generated](https://serverfault.com/questions/1134466/multiple-ldap-and-krbtgt-tickets-generated).

I read into Kerberos delegation, but unfortunately more questions arose than answers..

1. Why do we need a different TGT at all when requesting a service 'behind' another service in the same realm? A single TGT (which could always be forwardable) seems to be good to request several STs for different servers (if contacted directly by the client). What's the drawback af using the original TGT for a service on e.g. an SQL-Server behind a webserver?
2. According to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/ba-p/395463 the client itself never requests a second TGT from the DC for delegation (Server 1 does). Why do I see one in my cache?
3. According to https://attl4s.github.io/assets/pdf/You_do_(not)_Understand_Kerberos_Delegation.pdf page 55 the client does request the delegation TGT (that's in contradiction to 2)) directly after requestion the origianl TGT. How does the client know at that time that a delegation will be neccessary, when web01 wasn't even conatcted yet?

```
C:\Windows\system32>klist

Aktuelle Anmelde-ID ist 0:0x166da1

Zwischengespeicherte Tickets: (10)

#0>     Client: xxx.xxx @ BAG.INT
        Server: krbtgt/BAG.INT @ BAG.INT
        KerbTicket (Verschlüsselungstyp): AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticketkennzeichen 0x60a10000 -> forwardable forwarded renewable pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Startzeit: 11/8/2023 7:31:02 (lokal)
        Endzeit:   11/8/2023 17:30:59 (lokal)
        Erneuerungszeit: 11/15/2023 7:30:59 (lokal)
        Sitzungsschlüsseltyp: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cachekennzeichen: 0x2 -> DELEGATION
        KDC aufgerufen: DC2.BAG.INT

#1>     Client: xxx.xxx@ BAG.INT
        Server: krbtgt/BAG.INT @ BAG.INT
        KerbTicket (Verschlüsselungstyp): AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Ticketkennzeichen 0x40e10000 -> forwardable renewable initial pre_authent name_canonicalize
        Startzeit: 11/8/2023 7:30:59 (lokal)
        Endzeit:   11/8/2023 17:30:59 (lokal)
        Erneuerungszeit: 11/15/2023 7:30:59 (lokal)
        Sitzungsschlüsseltyp: AES-256-CTS-HMAC-SHA1-96
        Cachekennzeichen: 0x1 -> PRIMARY
        KDC aufgerufen: DC2
```

Comment: Can you show the actual `klist` output you're talking about?

Comment: just added the klist-output of the two TGTs to the original post. Would the other tickets (STs) be of interest too?

Answer (score 0):

When you see multiple TGTs (Ticket Granting Tickets) listed when you run the klist command on your machine, it means that you have obtained multiple Kerberos tickets for different services or purposes.

Comment: But the idea of a TGT is to use a single TGT for all STs in the realm, or not?
Seeing that I currently have 2 TGTs and 8 STs in my klist-output, it sounds a bit arbitrary, which STs can be requested with the original TGT and which require an extra TGT.
I'm sure there is a reason, I currently don't understand it.
Taking Jason Garmans example from his kerberos book with the drivers license (TGT) that get's me admission to a club (ST), it feels like it's OK for club A but the bouncer of Club B in the same city only accepts a license from Maine and won't accept mine from California. Why?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do we need a different TGT at all when requesting a service 'behind' another service in the same realm?

The "delegation" TGT differs in one or possibly two ways:

1. It has the 'Forwarded' flag set, in addition to the usual 'Forwardable' and such. (You can see this in your klist output.)
2. If the original TGT had a non-empty 'Addresses' list, a new TGT needs to be issued in order to update the list.

More on point #2: In the past (Kerberos IV and early Kerberos 5), Kerberos tickets used to be IP-limited – the TGT was issued with your IP address in it (to mitigate possible ticket stealing from /tmp/krb5cc), so in order for delegation to work, the client needed to get a new TGT that instead had Server1's IP address instead.

Now, Active Directory never used IP-limited tickets (and non-AD Kerberos does not use them anymore, either) so Windows only needs to cache one 'Forwarded' TGT for everything, but still, the protocol remains the same: the original TGT is not delegated but a new one is made from it (and the 'Forwarded' flag is still set as before).

```
$ kinit -a
Password for grawity@EXAMPLE.NET: *****

$ klist -fan
Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2023-11-09 11:30:30  2023-11-10 11:30:28  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.NET@EXAMPLE.NET
    Flags: FIA (Forwardable Initial pre-Authenticated)
    Addresses: 10.35.14.3, 10.147.36.8, 2001:db8::36c4:e19f:3c1:8a8

$ ssh -K exampleHost klist -fan
Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
11/09/2023 09:30:54  11/10/2023 09:30:28  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.NET@EXAMPLE.NET
    Flags: FfAT (Forwardable forwarded pre-Authenticated Transit-policy-checked)
    Addresses: 10.147.1.3
```

<sup>(Flag names were manually added to the "Flags:" line for demonstration purposes.)</sup>

> According to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/ba-p/395463 the client itself never requests a second TGT from the DC for delegation (Server 1 does). Why do I see one in my cache?

It actually does. The article omits that part, because functionally the TGTs are identical except for the second TGT having a 'Forwarded' flag (in addition to 'Forwardable'), so in most cases it's not really worth talking about.

> According to https://attl4s.github.io/assets/pdf/You_do_(not)_Understand_Kerberos_Delegation.pdf page 55 the client does request the delegation TGT (that's in contradiction to 2)) directly after requestion the origianl TGT. How does the client know at that time that a delegation will be neccessary, when web01 wasn't even conatcted yet?

The web01 server *has* been contacted, it's just not shown. The capture is incomplete; parts of it have been deliberately trimmed out for demonstration purposes. (Note how the SMB "Negotiate protocol version" packets are missing, too, even though they would've been sent over the same connection.)

I suspect it was made using the Wireshark display filter `kerberos`, which includes only those packets that Wireshark recognizes as containing an AS/TGS/AP REQ/REP messages – but does not include the initial unauthenticated GET and its "401 Auth needed" response.

But it's feasible to obtain the delegation TGT without knowing the service will be web01 – as mentioned before, the delegated TGT is not specific to the target service in any way (unconstrained delegation doesn't mark the delegated tickets with their intended recipient – the only difference would've been the IP address list), which means the TGT doesn't necessarily need to be *for web01* in particular – it could have been acquired for something else. So hypothetically it could be that the TGT is cached because delegation was done for *another* service moments earlier, or it's pre-cached "just in case" (I don't think Windows does pre-caching like that).

Comment: First of all: thanks a lot for taking the time to explain things to me. It's a bit clearer now although still far from crystal clear. But it'll do.

Comment: Good answer. On Windows, `klist tgt` will show the single cached primary/initial TGT.

Comment: @KaiK: a better example would be useful for clarity. In 99% of cases, delegation is a web server front ending an application. The client has zero knowledge of what services the web server is fronting, or the tickets to request. The server simply says "401", and the client sends an existing ticket base64 encoded in the auth header, which includes group membership on Windows. An application running on the web server, running as a different user account, creates a separate thread and impersonates the identity of the user, and *optionally*, access non-local resources (aka "delegation token").